# Chat faq & help update add tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, chat, faq-update-request

I saw [tag](/questions/tagged/tag)'s in the security.se chat today so I looked in the help box but I didn't find anything about tags there so i moved on into the faq but there was noting about tags there either. So is it possible to update the help and or the faq to include how to make tags?

I have spent some time in the sand box and i wasn't able to create any tags i tried following but it didn't work.

```
[tag:tag]
```

Comment: Doing this as a comment since it isn't about actually updating the faq/help:  `[tag:tag]` only works in chat rooms that are associated with a site, ie, not the sandbox.  Try exactly what you have there in the ITS chat room.

Comment: @Rebecca Chernoff Thank you, but the issue still remains its not documented, or at least not in the place you'd look for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, previously it hadn't been "frequently asked"... ;p I've added it now, so it'll go out with the next deploy.